# how to trigger or click a button inside iframe using DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

Is this possible? im trying to click a div inside an iframe using angular / typescript. i have been trying to manipulate it via dom but still unable to click is

```
<iframe class="component-frame" src="index.html">
</iframe>
```

index.html

```
<div class="click-div">
i want to click this!
</div>
```

on my component, i have this function

```
clickCheckout() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('component-frame').contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('click-div"').click();
}
```

but giving me this error:

Property 'contentDocument' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf'.ts(2339)

any inputs or suggestion on how to achieve this? thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but the error you're getting is because `contentDocument` is not a property of `HTMLCollectionOf`. `getElementsByClassName` does not return a single element, as the name implies.